# Doing a std::endl before AllocConsole causes no display of std::cout

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to redirect traces on an output console on Windows Visual 2012, Linker/Subsystem = Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS), using a classical RedirectIOToConsole function.

Performing std::endl before AllocConsole seems to causes problems to display traces.

Below is my test:

```
#include <windows.h>     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>  
void RedirectIOToConsole()
{
  FILE *conin, *conout; 
  AllocConsole();
  freopen_s(&conin, "conin$", "r", stdin);
  freopen_s(&conout, "conout$", "w", stdout);
  freopen_s(&conout, "conout$", "w", stderr);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  // std::cout << "My Trace 1";              // Uncomment this line for Test 1
  // std::cout << "My Trace 1" << std::endl; // Uncomment this line for Test 2
  RedirectIOToConsole();
  printf( "redirected console\n");
  std::cout << "My Trace 2" << std::endl;
  ch = getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

- Run it as it is - output in Console window:

redirected console

My Trace 2
-> OK

- Uncomment line for test 1 - output in Console window:

redirected console

My Trace 2
-> OK

- Uncomment line for test 2 - output in Console window:

redirected console
-> NOK

Comment: `std::cout` is buffered, `std::endl;` flushes the buffer. Hope that helps, because I didn't understand the problem/question at all.

Comment: The first thing you should do is check for error from the functions you're calling. And if they indicate an error, you might want to check what error that is (with e.g. `GetLastError` for `AllocConsole` or the returned value for `freopen_s`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before you call `RedirectIOToConsole()` there is nothing for `cout` to output onto. Since `cout` is buffered, the output is stored in a buffer until a `flush` is performed. `endl` contains a `flush`.

When you try to flush the output with no console available, the `cout` stream sets the `badbit` in the `iostate`.

When you then do the next step of `cout << "My Trace 2" << endl;` the output is not proceeding because before actually writing the data to the output file (stdout), `cout` checks the `iostate` and says "Oh, this is not good, we have `badbit` set" and bails out without trying to write.

You could, in theory, fix this by calling [`cout.clear();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), but I would suggest that it's a better plan to not call `cout` before you have allocated a console - it serves no purpose to output things before you have something to output to.